# Blank first cell breaks conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a sheet like this.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| Row 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| Row 3 | 2 |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Row 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |  |

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight cells in B1:F4 by comparing them to the cell in column A of the same row.

My conditional formatting rule is set like this.

```
Range: B1:F4
Rules: Custom formula
=B1>=$A1
Formatting style: Background color green
```

I expect no green cells in row 1 and B2:D2, D3:E3, and B4:C4 to be green.

The first two rows and the last row work fine, but row 3 is all white. If I put anything even text into B3 then the rule works on row 3. This formula/rule does work in Excel.

My questions are:

- Why is this happening? I think I'm missing something about how the custom formula works.
- How can I fix this without putting something in column B on each row?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with another formatting rule that applied to the same cells and used the formula `=$B1<>""` so if the first cell was empty the entire row had its background set to white.